# How can i join 2 json file on the basis of common key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Input test.json -

```
{"strikers": [
    { "name": "Alexis Sanchez", "club": "Manchester United" },
    { "name": "Robin van Persie", "club": "Feyenoord" }
] }
```

test1.json

```
{"strikers": [
    { "name": "Nicolas Pepe", "club": "Arsenal" }
] }
```

Expected Output result.json

```
{"strikers": [
    { "name": "Alexis Sanchez", "club": "Manchester United" },
    { "name": "Robin van Persie", "club": "Feyenoord" },
    { "name": "Nicolas Pepe", "club": "Arsenal" }
] }
```

My Output

```
{"strikers": [

    { "name": "Alexis Sanchez", "club": "Manchester United" },
    { "name": "Robin van Persie", "club": "Feyenoord" }
    ] }, 
    {"strikers": [
        { "name": "Nicolas Pepe", "club": "Arsenal" }
] }
```

I have written this piece of code and not sure how to move ahead. Can anybody help me in this ?

```
def mangle(s):
    return s.strip()[1:-1]

input_filenames = ["test.json", "test1.json"]
with file("result.json", "w") as outfile:
    first = True
    for infile_name in input_filenames:
        with file(infile_name) as infile:
            if first:
                outfile.write('[')
                first = False
            else:
                outfile.write(',')
            outfile.write(mangle(infile.read()))
    outfile.write(']')
```

Comment: Check [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) :)

Comment: Your actual output isn't valid JSON.

Comment: you should try json.loads()

Comment: @Ouss actually, `json.load()` and `json.dump()`

Comment: I have no idea what you guys are talking about. There is nothing special about JSON and it's been deserialized

Comment: You want to append a dictionary to a list

Comment: @roganjosh No he doesn't, he wants to combine lists from two dictionaries.

Comment: @Barmar so... they want to append items from one list to another? I'm not seeing where I'm incorrect here

Answer (score 2):

python has a useful `json` library, you could do something like this:

```py
import json
json1 = '''{"strikers": [
    { "name": "Alexis Sanchez", "club": "Manchester United" },
    { "name": "Robin van Persie", "club": "Feyenoord" }
    ] }'''

json2 = '''{"strikers": [
    { "name": "Nicolas Pepe", "club": "Arsenal" }
    ] }'''

strikers_dict = json.loads(json1)
strikers_dict['strikers'].extend(json.loads(json2)['strikers'])

print(json.dumps(strikers_dict, indent=2))
```

this prints

```
{
  "strikers": [
    {
      "name": "Alexis Sanchez",
      "club": "Manchester United"
    },
    {
      "name": "Robin van Persie",
      "club": "Feyenoord"
    },
    {
      "name": "Nicolas Pepe",
      "club": "Arsenal"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.load()` to parse the JSON, and `json.dump()` to write JSON. Then concatenate the properties.

```
all_data = {}
for file in input_filenames:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for key in data:
        if key in all_data:
            all_data[key] += data[key]
        else:
            all_data[key] = data[key]

with open("result.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(outfile, all_data)
```

This code assumes that all the properties in the JSON are lists that need to be concatenated.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question

Comment: You have hardcoded the strikers. What is there is some different common key

Comment: Also there can be more than 1 common key

Comment: The question only showed one property, I've made the code more generic now.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive demo here: https://repl.it/repls/DullBeneficialConcentrate

```
import json

input_filenames = ["test.json", "test1.json"]

def read_json(file):
  with open(file, 'r') as f:
    return json.load(f)

data = [read_json(fn) for fn in input_filenames]

for k in data[0]:
  data[0][k].extend(data[1][k])

with open('result.json', 'w') as f:
  json.dump(data[0], f, indent=2)
```

result.json:

```
{
  "strikers": [
    {
      "name": "Alexis Sanchez",
      "club": "Manchester United"
    },
    {
      "name": "Robin van Persie",
      "club": "Feyenoord"
    },
    {
      "name": "Nicolas Pepe",
      "club": "Arsenal"
    }
  ]
}
```